# Basic authentication Android, JSON parsing, Вход в персональный кабинет сайта

Tags: java, android, json

Здравствуйте. У меня есть API для взятия данных из персонального кабинета. Но суть такова, что для начала надо пройти аутентификацию (Логин и пароль) скрин внизу. Как можно это реализовать? 
Нашел ответ на другом сайте, на все равно не понял.... 
Если можно, можете по подробнее написать, что и как мне надо сделать или какую нибудь ссылку скинуть... Заранее спасибо!
Если что вот этот другой сайт точно таким же вопросом как и мой:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698770/login-to-a-website-with-http-basic-authentication-from-android-app[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

```
...
URLConnection i1 = mySiteURL.openConnection(); // соединение с сайтом
i1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("username" + ":" + "password").getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", "")); // сообщаем сайту пароль
...
i1.connect();
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую)